# Should I share a how-to tutorial?

Tags: discussion, tutorials

Would I share an in depth tutorial on Ask Ubuntu or submit to Ubuntu.com?

---

I ask because I recently created a lengthy tutorial on how to setup your Node.js / MongoDB local environment(from source), make a simple app with it, and then deploy it with Juju.  It is a twelve page how-to(broken into 3 parts) and accompanied by a video series.  In case further look is required, details on it are at [YouTube.com](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2GrIUlxOcs&feature=share&list=PLCTh_XwrphiKQHpqSG8mz_74U0_nrGxar).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Yes, share it here on Ask Ubuntu.

It's perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question aka share an in depth how-to tutorial on Ask Ubuntu. [See this link in Help Center on Answering your own questions](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).

What I would suggest is to break down the tutorial in smaller independent parts and ask and answer different questions for them. Since you have already broken down your lengthy turorial into 3 different parts, you should ask them as separate questions. Link between them as you wish.

You may also link to your YouTube video series to further help in understanding the answer, just make sure you also provide a written explanation for the same over here on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have posted the first part. Thank you for your advice.  http://askubuntu.com/q/328681/88546